# How to find all combinations of all items in a set?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Let's say, there's a Product data-model. Product has the attribute - colour, which can, in this case, be red, black, yellow, white, orange. And which in total amounts to 5 different Products.

Now I want to introduce a new set of attributes, let's say, material - cotton, nilon, paper; and size - s, m, l, xl; this will amount to a bigger set of different Products, each of which of a different colour, material and size.

In total, there'll be 60 different combinations: 5 colours * 3 materials * 4 sizes = 60. Right?

Later I may want to introduce more attributes as well, therefore, a solution should not rely on the amount of attributes as a constant, because it's a variable.

**Q**:

What'll be an algorithm for creating a set of Products with all these attributes?

And is there a name for it?

The amount of attributes and their values become known at runtime only. And the amount of values of each attribute differ: one attribute can have A values, other B, other C...

**update1**

Trying to implement it using the odometer algorithm,I've created an array of integers:

```
--------------------------------------------------
3 (colour) |  4 (material)  | 5 (size) | 2 (design)
--------------------------------------------------
```

that is:

3 is the amount of **colour** values: red, blue, black

4 is the amount of **materials**: cotton, paper, iron, gold

5 is the amount of **sizes**: s, m, l, xl, xxl

2 is the amount of **design values**: cool, excellent

and so on..

This has been suggested:

`You always start with incrementing the first array entry by one, until it gets an overflow...[...]`

but what would it give me?

```
unique_variants = []
for i in my_array:
  # i = 3 ===> ++ 3 new variants
  # i = 4 ===> ++ 4 new variants
  # i = 5 ===> ++ 5 new variants
  # i = 2 ===> ++ 2 new variants

  # [......]     


====>
3 + 4 + 5 + 2 = 14 unique variants (wrong)
```

that is, it'd be a sum, whereas what I need is to multiply, thus creating 120 unique variants:

```
3 * 4 * 5 * 2 = 120 unique variants (right)
```

Or, better yet, I need those unique combinations themselves, for instance:

- product1 (red, iron, m, cool)
- product2 (red, paper, m, cool)
- product3 (blue, iron, s, excellent)
- .....
- product N (black, gold, xxl, excellent)

....

Comment: What you're missing is that when an array entry gets an overflow, it gets reset, and the process repeats: after (black, cotton, s, cool) you get (red, paper, s, cool), and after that (blue, paper, s, cool) and so on. This will generate all 120 variants, and is equivalent to Doc Browns's odometer, at a different level of abstraction.

Comment: @Jasmijn how precisely? Doc Brown's solution is difficult to follow as there're some things omitted that are, probably, too obvious to him, therefore, I have a half of a solution now

Comment: It's hard to fill in the missing code at this high level of abstraction as the devil is in the details, but basically you'd add a copy of `a` to your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for this is *Cartesian product*.

Python has a function for this, and the documentation for it shows code that's roughly equivalent to what the function itself does:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

(See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=product#itertools.product)

Or, if you're using Python, you could just use `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say there are n different attributes, the first one having k<sub>1</sub> different values, the second one k<sub>2</sub>, ..., the n-th one k<sub>n</sub>.

The most straightforward algorithm here is to implement an **odometer**. Just create an integer array with n entries. The i-th entry is going to run through the values 0,..., k<sub>i</sub>-1. You always start with incrementing the first array entry by one, until it gets an overflow which causes it to be reset to zero and the second entry to be incremented by one, until it gets an overflow, then increment the third entry, and so on. In pseudocode  (`a` is the array holding the "odometer digits", starting with all elements set to zero. `k` is the array holding the number of values for each attribute):

```
 p=1;
 for(i=0;i<n;++i)
 {
    p*=k[i];
    a[i]=0;
 }

 for(j=0;j<p;++j)
 {
    //...
    // Add some code here which takes the current state
    // of the array a and maps it to a product object
    // with the corresponding attribute values.
    //...
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
       a[i]++;
       if(a[i] < k[i])
          break;
       a[i]=0;
    }
 }
```

This will produce all k<sub>1</sub> x ... x k<sub>n</sub> combinations.

I leave it as an exercise to you to create the different products from an "odometer state".

Comment: I don't understand - what do I actually a) *do* an each increment b) how I increment it?

Comment: @RayanLemi: do you know what an odometer is and have an idea, how to implement it, lets say, with the usual digits from 0 to 9?

Comment: an odometer is a device in a car; odometer algorithm - not yet, but I can do a research

Comment: @RayanLemi: I think before googling this, you should really try to implement this by yourself.

Comment: look at my update please

Comment: @RayanLemi: ok, I added some pseudo code for the "increment" part.

Comment: I think that your code won't work for *my* task, because: -- where is the final result stored? in the `a` variable which is an array of integers? a)  why do you throw away a result on each iteration by `a[i] = 0`? b) I need not an array of integers but unique combinations themselves

Comment: @RayanLemi: sorry, but now this becomes more and more a coding question, which can be asked on Stackoverflow, not here. What I showed above is the "increment" part, which must be inside an outer loop, where the states in the array `a` have to be mapped to the different attribute values of "Product" (which, as I wrote, I left as an exercise for you). I recommend you implement the above loop in your famous programming language and use a debugger to find out why it works.

Comment: @DocBrown please correct me if I am wrong, but I think your solution is not flexible enough. He would have to create a mapper each time something changed. For example: generating target class with (color, material) would require different mapper than generating (material, color). So it's architecturally wrong unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @BlažMrak: it will be pretty straightforward to map a list of attributes to a correctly initialized array `k` in a generic manner before the algorithm starts, and to map a specific state of the array `a` back to the matching attribute values. So yes, you probably misunderstood this.

Comment: What happens if k changes? Doesn't that mean that you have to modify the mapper? As far as I know the mapper can only map array a of a certain length - number of attributes still matters to you

Comment: @BlažMrak: as I said, k has to be initialized in a generic manner (at run time, so it matches the number of attributes and attribute values of `Product`). How this is accomplished depends on the programming language used by the OP, and the way `Product` and its attributes are implemented, but it is actually just an implementation detail.

Comment: Product can have any number of attributes. If you know the number of attributes you will have at runtime, you can do nested for loops... What your solution does is moves the hardcoding from generation, to the initialization, but it is still hardcoded - it still depends on the number of attributes. As you said - "correctly initialized" - this means that you have to know how to correctly initialize it or it will fail.

Comment: @BlažMrak: if one knows the number `n` of attributes *only* at runtime, but not at compile time, one cannot implement this by using nested loops. The OP was supposing a `Product` with a variable number of attributes, so they must have already implemented some kind of attribute-value model, where the number "n" and the k[i] can be retrieved from.

Comment: `sorry, but now this becomes more and more a coding question, which can be asked on Stackoverflow, not here` - no, still the one of algorithm. How would you algorithm produce at least the number "128" (unique combinations) with the input data in my "update1"? Or what is it  that it'll  produce at all?

Comment: @DocBrown the pseudo code is really confusing, as it only makes one step and then finishes.

Comment: @RayanLemi: (sigh)  - this will be my final edit. Now please implement this in your favorite programming language and **use a debugger** to see how it works.

Comment: @BlažMrak: maybe you missed my last edit?

Comment: @DocBrown I did

Comment: what's the 3rd loop for?

Comment: @RayanLemi: did you implement the code and used a debugger to single-step through it, as I wrote?

Comment: Doc Brown - yes.

Comment: @RayanLemi: well, then if you think something is not needed in my pseudo code, feel free to leave it out and check what happens.

Comment: First of all, your pseudo code doesn't work, even after translate to proper C because there're a few things that you've omitted

Comment: @RayanLemi: well, I guess that is why it is called *pseudo* code. But when you have a specific, constructive critics, I am open to hear it - "does not work" is nothing I consider to be such a critics.

Comment: Well, you have to be specific: this is something I call an algorithm and "that's why it's called pseudo code", figure it out by yourself -- is nothing I consider to be an answer

Comment: @RayanLemi: well, that sounds a lot to me like all you want is coding help. As I said, here is the wrong place for it. I am glad you found an answer which finally seem to help you, using an inbuilt Python mechanism, but I doubt you will learn really from it how to tackle such kind of problems when there is no such out-of-the-box solution available.

Comment: well, that sounds a lot to me like all you want that you defend your wrong position

Answer (score 0):

Suppose each attribute can be modeled as a nonnegative integer in some range, [0, max(k)], for the kth attribute. Suppose further the list of attributes is modeled as an array of length n such that the kth value of the array is the value of the kth attribute. For example, if you have two attributes, color and size, and color is red or green and size is skall, medium or large, the array [0, 1] might represent red and medium.

A recursive solution to enumerate all possible array values is this:

```
EnumerateAll()
    EnumerateAllInternal(new uint[n], 0)

EnumerateAllInternal(soln, place)
    if place >= n then
        print soln
    else
        for i = 0 to max(place)
            soln(place) = i
            EnumerateAll(soln, place + 1)

call Enumerate()
```

This recursive solution works by performing depth-first search on an implicit tree whose non-root nodes are the values the attributes can take.

Comment: what is `soln`? and what's `place`?

Answer (score -2):

```
for(color: colorList) {
  for(material: materialList) {
    products.append(new Product(color, material))
  }
}
```

"nested for loop" I will call it. Whenever you add another property to the product, add a new list and a loop. It is stupid, but it will work.

EDIT: I don't know what this is or how it is called, but I think it does what you want it to do.

```
public class AttributeGeneration
    class Attribute {}

    class Attribute1 extends Attribute
    {
        String prop;

        public Attribute1(String prop)
        {
            this.prop = prop;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Attribute1{" +
                    "prop='" + prop + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class Attribute2 extends Attribute
    {
        String prop;

        public Attribute2(String prop)
        {
            this.prop = prop;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Attribute2{" +
                    "prop='" + prop + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class Builder
    {
        Attribute1 attribute1;
        Attribute2 attribute2;

        public Builder withAttribute(Attribute attribute)
        {
            if (attribute instanceof Attribute1)
            {
                this.attribute1 = (Attribute1) attribute;
            }
            else if (attribute instanceof Attribute2)
            {
                this.attribute2 = (Attribute2) attribute;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public Target build()
        {
            return new Target(attribute1, attribute2);
        }
    }

    class Target
    {
        Attribute1 attribute1;
        Attribute2 attribute2;

        public Target(
                Attribute1 attribute1,
                Attribute2 attribute2
        )
        {
            this.attribute1 = attribute1;
            this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Target{" +
                    "attribute1=" + attribute1 +
                    ", attribute2=" + attribute2 +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static List<Target> result = new ArrayList<>();

    class Constatns
    {
        List<Attribute1> attribute1s = List.of(
                new Attribute1("A1P1"),
                new Attribute1("A1P2"),
                new Attribute1("A1P3")
        );
        List<Attribute2> attribute2s = List.of(
                new Attribute2("A2P1"),
                new Attribute2("A2P2"),
                new Attribute2("A2P3")
        );
        List<List<? extends Attribute>> attributes = List.of(attribute1s, attribute2s);
    }


    public void generate(
            List<List<? extends Attribute>> attributeList,
            int depth,
            Builder builder
    )
    {
        List<? extends Attribute> attributes = attributeList.get(depth);

        for (Attribute attribute :
                attributes)
        {
            builder.withAttribute(attribute);

            if (isLeaf(attributeList, depth))
            {
                result.add(builder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                generate(attributeList, depth + 1, builder);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isLeaf(
            List<List<? extends Attribute>> attributeList,
            int depth
    )
    {
        return depth == attributeList.size() - 1;
    }

    @Test
    @Tag("special")
    void test()
    {
        var constants = new Constatns();

        generate(constants.attributes, 0, new Builder());

        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result.size());
    }
}
```

You can run the above code with JUnit if you want.

My idea was to recursively walk over all "branches" and generate the target class in the leafs. The builder is basically an object that represents the state of the Target class at a certain node.

Comment: .that is wrong.

Comment: You seemed to have missed the OPs edit: *"a solution should not rely on the amount of attributes as a constant, because it's a variable."*

Comment: I understood that as "number of attributes of the list", no as the number of lists. I'll update my post.

Comment: I don't use Java, nor do I want to overcomplicate a solution so much: classes, OOP, inheritance, mapping... I don't need any of this. I need only a simple algorithm in Python, C or pseudo-code

Comment: Also, the amount of attributes and the values of each attribute comes at runtime, from a user

Comment: @RayanLemi This generate function works with any list, not just the ones I defined. Also, "I don't want to overcomplicate" and "amount of attributes and values comes at runtime" contradict each other, assuming you don't know what those attributes look like. If you don't know what the target object would look like, then see Doc's answer. You will still need to do some smart mapping though.